# Is there a program to show programs loading during the boot process in real time?

Tags: windows, boot, monitoring

There are any number of programs that will show me WHAT will run during the boot process for Windows XP. I've always been partial to Mike Lin's version but there are several others, some of which are quite possibly superior. That's not the issue.

What I'd really like is a program that would load first and then would list the programs that were about to load and then check them off as the programs loaded. This isn't something I necessarily need for myself. But certain family members get click happy as soon as they see the icon they eventually want to run and end up clicking on it. THIRTY TWO TIMES in one memorable crash-inducing spasm.

If there was some way for 'progress' to be shown during the loading of from the various spots Windows auto-loads from, PLUS a BIG BANNER saying "Please do not move the mouse or click on anything until done.", I think I might cut down on my early morning family support calls significantly.

I've tried a variety of searches, but I couldn't find the ones that show in real time in the forest of links to programs that will show the list after the fact. Any leads? If not, do any of you who write the after-the-fact listers want to take a shot at producing a utility to do what I think would be a relatively popular utility?

Best of the season to all of you and yours.

Thanks in advance for any replies, GM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sounds a fair bit like [soluto](http://www.soluto.com/) - does roughly that, and works pretty well on anything but thinkpads (it messes with the TPM chips they have)

Comment: It certainly appears that you've found the solution. I am experimenting with it on one of my machines. It's certainly lovely and it gave good advice on the various denizens of the startup on that machine. Afterwards, although, the machine seemed to run a bit slow. A few more days of experimentation are probably needed. But a temp green check mark. Thanks very much for the link.

Comment: It took some time due to a virus attack that forced a restore and then re-install. But I have since absolved Soluto of any involvement in the problem. And, I had to backup doing any delayed running of programs on the machine in question, Soluto is exactly the solution to the problem. I liked it so much, I'm keeping it on my computer too. Thanks so very much for the suggestion.

Comment: `Soluto` is lovely! I've just watched their demos and have loved the tool already for now.